# Почему файл не добавляется в .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

Я составил `.gitignore` файл положил его в корень проекта в файле есть указание на то что нужно игнорировать файлы типа `.idea/workspace.xml`

> `#` Intellij
>
> *.iml
>
> .idea/workspace.xml
>
> .idea/libraries

Но все равно когда пишу `git status` получаю

```
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified:   .idea/workspace.xml
```

Что делаю не так?

Comment: может быть вот так `/.idea/workspace.xml` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строка

```
modified:   .idea/workspace.xml
```

говорит что офайл уже в индексе, это значит что его для начала нужно перестать отслеживать

```
git rm --cached .idea/workspace.xml
```

[GIT rm](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm)

после этого если файл правильно добавлен в [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)
то при команде

```
git status
```

файла не доолжно быть

Добавление `gitignore`

```
git add .gitignore 
git commit -m"gitignore was updated"
gut push origin master
```

Comment: А если я уже сделал `git add .` и залил все, то теперь нужно сделать так git rm --cached .idea/workspace.xml, потом я делаю git commit -m и потом git push ? Так?

Comment: послу удаления из индекса и добавления в гитигнор сам файл гитигнора будет modify и его(файл гитигнора ) нужно будет комитеть

Comment: поправит код с добавлением gitignore, смотри

Answer (score 3):

Файл `.gitignore` влияет только на те файлы, которые для репозитория новые. Ваш файл `.idea/workspace.xml` уже лежит в репозитории - а потому продолжает отслеживаться.

Вам надо удалить его (или переместить в другое место), после чего зафиксировать удаление в репозитории. После этого старый файл можно будет вернуть на место и гит больше не будет предлагать его добавить.

Comment: Я сегодня первый день пользуюсь гитом, так что за раннее сорри)) Но если я правильно понял, то я должен сделать так `git rm --cached .idea/workspace.xml`, потом я делаю `git commit -m`  и потом `git push` ? Так?